# How to create 4 squares (like the Windows logo) in C# using loops and if statements?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, if-statement, for-loop, console-application

I want to create a program that outputs 4 squares that looks like the Windows logo. So far I've managed to create 2 squares that look like this:

```
[ ]

[ ]
```

I've made 2 vertical squares first. So how do you add the other 2 vertical squares to complete the Windows logo?

```
[ ] [ ]

[ ] [ ]
```

Here's my code:

```
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
        Console.Clear();
        int size = 10;
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int row = 3; row <= size; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col <= size + 1; col++)
            {
                if (col == 0)
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
                    Console.Write(" ");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    Console.Write(" ");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int row = 3; row <= size; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col <= size + 1; col++)
            {
                if (col == 0)
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
                    Console.Write(" ");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    Console.Write(" ");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Homework ???????

Comment: You should draw two at a time! Also, I like this it's like return to the 60's :)

Comment: Duplicate the inner loops for both of the outer loops. Worked for me! Here's a [screenshot](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/m2my4)

Comment: My goodness that was simple. Thank you! It worked for me as well. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code (on which you should work a lot) changed so it should draw what you want. I would suggest refactor it a little bit. Note that you should increase the size to at least double and to write once DarkCyan after you draw the first rectangle (at the middle of the size). Check the code:

```
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
            Console.Clear();
            int size = 20;
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int row = 3; row <= size/2; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col <= size + 1; col++)
                {
                    if (col == 0 || col == size/2 +1)
                    {
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
                        Console.Write(" ");
                        Console.ResetColor();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                        Console.Write(" ");
                        Console.ResetColor();
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int row = 3; row <= size/2; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col <= size + 1; col++)
                {
                    if (col == 0 || col == size / 2 + 1)
                    {
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
                        Console.Write(" ");
                        Console.ResetColor();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                        Console.Write(" ");
                        Console.ResetColor();
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I'm studying it now.

Though, the squares look taller than what I want it to be.

Comment: It works great! I like how you shortened the code using OR operators. :D

Comment: @user1771083 By changing the value of size and conditions in for loops you will be able to change the size of squares. The code is hard to read so that is why I suggested you to refactor it.

Comment: @user1771083 My intention wasn't to rewrite your code but to change it in way that you can learn from it. Now try to put everything in two loops instead of four, that should be the next step.

Comment: I've adjusted the values accordingly. It now displays a squarer square.

I'm now working on making it with just two loops. But your post answers my original question. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

In the first step write a helper method to draw something:

```
public static class Draw
{
    public static void Rectangle(int top, int left, int width, int height, ConsoleColor color)
    {
        if (width < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("width must be greater or equal zero.", "width");

        if (height < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("height must be greater or equal zero.", "height");

        var oldPositionLeft = Console.CursorLeft;
        var oldPositionTop = Console.CursorTop;
        var oldColor = Console.BackgroundColor;

        Console.BackgroundColor = color;

        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top + i);
            Console.Write(new String(' ', width));
        }

        Console.SetCursorPosition(oldPositionLeft, oldPositionTop);
        Console.BackgroundColor = oldColor;
    }
```

Then define the items you'd like to draw:

```
var items = new[] 
{ 
    new 
    { 
        Color = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan,
        Top = 1,
        Left = 1,
        Size = 5
    },
    new 
    { 
        Color = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen,
        Top = 1,
        Left = 7,
        Size = 5
    },
    new 
    { 
        Color = ConsoleColor.DarkRed,
        Top = 7,
        Left = 1,
        Size = 5
    },
    new 
    { 
        Color = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow,
        Top = 7,
        Left = 7,
        Size = 5
    },
};
```

Then simply iterate over the elements and draw them:

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    Draw.Rectangle(item.Top, item.Left, item.Size, item.Size, item.Color);
}
```

Comment: I'm not yet familiar with the 'var' and helper methods. :\

But thanks for sharing this different method of drawing the squares. It would come in handy for my class participation grade. :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
>
> ```
>         Console.Clear();
>         int size = 10;
>         Console.WriteLine();
>         for (int row = 3; row <= size; row++)
>         {
>             for (int col = 0; col <= size + 1; col++)
>             {
>                 if (col == 0)
>                 {
>                     Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
>                     Console.Write(" ");
>                     Console.ResetColor();
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
>                     Console.Write(" ");
>                     Console.ResetColor();
>                 }
>
>             }
>             for (int col = 0; col <= size + 1; col++)
>             {
>                 if (col == 0)
>                 {
>                     Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
>                     Console.Write(" ");
>                     Console.ResetColor();
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
>                     Console.Write(" ");
>                     Console.ResetColor();
>                 }
>             }
>             Console.WriteLine();
>         }
>         Console.WriteLine();
>         for (int row = 3; row <= size; row++)
>         {
>             for (int col = 0; col <= size + 1; col++)
>             {
>                 if (col == 0)
>                 {
>                     Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
>                     Console.Write(" ");
>                     Console.ResetColor();
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
>                     Console.Write(" ");
>                     Console.ResetColor();
>                 }
>             }
>             for (int col = 0; col <= size + 1; col++)
>             {
>                 if (col == 0)
>                 {
>                     Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
>                     Console.Write(" ");
>                     Console.ResetColor();
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
>                     Console.Write(" ");
>                     Console.ResetColor();
>                 }
>             }
>             Console.WriteLine();
>         }
>        
>
>         Console.ReadKey();
> ```